# Extension preventing before_body_end from rendering anything else

Tags: configurable-product, blocks, bundled-product

I'm using an extension from Firebear for configurable products and bundled products. When I enable that extension, `before_body_end` only shows the Firebear block and none of the other blocks which should be there. If I disable Firebear, all the other blocks show up fine.

The only code I can see where Firebear references `before_body_end` is in `layout/firebear_configurl.xml`:

```
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <catalog_product_view>
        <reference name="before_body_end">
            <block type="page/html_head" name="fbfoot" as="fbfoot" template="firebear/html/foot.phtml">
                <action ifconfig="firebear_configurl/general/enabled" method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>js/firebear/configurl.js</name></action>
                <action ifconfig="firebear_configurl/general/enabled" method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>js/firebear/jquery.history.min.js</name></action>
            </block>
        </reference>
    </catalog_product_view>
</layout>
```

How could Firebear be doing this and how might I prevent it?

**Update**

Extension Disabled - The extension has a property called "Enable Improved Configurable Product". I set that property to "No" to disable it:

[image]

Extension enabled:

[image]

Comment: In above mension block, some jquery file added. So there can be confliction issue.

Comment: I don't think it's a client side issue. There are no script errors and the server side blocks are not being rendered - updated OP

Comment: How did you disable the extension? The block is still there in your "Extension disabled" screenshot, so either you did not clear the layout cache or you did not actually disable the extension. Maybe you just used "disable module output"?

Comment: The extension has a property called "Enable Improved Configurable Product". I set that property to "No" to disable it.

Comment: It's probably doing something in an observer, but since the layout object is globally accessible with `Mage::getSingleton('core/layout')`, it could remove blocks accidentally or on purpose almost anywhere. Without having access to the source code, I cannot tell you more. Try to contact their support, since it is obviously a bug.